# Is there a way to view which command was executed by a VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to see which command has been executed by VSCode's extensions. For example, command executed by Spring Boot Dashboard (I was trying to simulate the command using terminal but without success).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how the extension implements its functions, reading its source code is a choice. For example, here is where Spring Boot Dashboard for VS Code is hosted: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-spring-boot-dashboard.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good idea. It would also be very helpful if we can look at the extension's execution output at runtime.